# Windowsでアンダースコアを(_)shiftを使わずに打ちたい

Tags: windows, key-mapping

Windows10でアンダースコアを入力するときはshift-\と入力しますがMacに慣れているためshiftなしで打てるようにしたいです

ただ極力、ほかのソフトウェア(AutoHotKeyなど)を使わずに設定を変更したいのですが可能でしょうか?

Comment: 「Macに慣れているため」というのが良くわからないのですが、Macでもアンダースコアを入力するにはShiftキーを使うのではないでしょうか。Macの方で何か設定を変えてらっしゃいませんか？

Comment: Macではshift keyを押さなくても"ろ" keyを押せば入力ができたと思います

Comment: すいません、特定のMacではそのように入力すれば(Shiftキーを押さなくても)アンダースコアが入力できることが確認できました。